# Expected time between successive visits in a Markov Chain?

Tags: expectation, markov-chains

This is a pretty basic question and I know the answer is probably really obvious, but I am having trouble reasoning as to why the following is true:

(From my lecture notes):

"""
Expected time between consecutive visits: Let h<sub>ii</sub> be the expected time between successive vists by an ergodic Markov chain to state i. Then,

$h_{ii} = 1/\pi_i$.

Since the Markov Chain spends $\pi_i$ fraction of time in state i, it must be that the expected time between successive visits to that state is $1/\pi_i$.

"""

So for example if $\pi_2$ = 1/3, then if the system has been running for a long time and someone from the outside looks in, the probablity of finding a particle in state 2 is 1/3. Then, the expected time between successive visits is 3. That last part is what doesn't make sense to me. Why is it that the expected number of visits to state i is 1/(probability of finding a particle in state i)? How can this be true for any n-state graph?

Any intuition would help me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way to understand this: Think of “outside observer finds the system in state $i$” as a Bernoulli trial with probability $\mathbf\pi_i$ of success. It’s easy to show that the expected number of trials required to produce a success is $1/\mathbf\pi_i$.

Comment: Oh, so do you mean the geometric distribution? Like, the outside observer keeps looking in (a bernoulli trial) and since we want to know the number of trials until he actually sees the particle in state two, then this is a geometrically distributed random variable, with prob. of success = $\pi$. Then, the expected value of this is 1/$pi$.

Comment: @Joe That’s it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

amd's answer gives some intuition for why this is true but I want to point out that it's not really a geometric distribution since it isn't memoryless.

Consider a very simple Markov chain with states 1 and 2 and transition probabilities of 0.99 for 1$\to$2 and 2$\to$1.  By symmetry, the particle will spend 50% of its time in each state, and indeed it typically visits state 1 every other turn.

But this isn't a Bernoulli trial or a geometric distribution: if we have just seen the particle at state 1, then it will be in state 2 on the next turn with 99% probability, not 50%.  The trials are not independent.

What's really happening is this: consider the state of the particle across a long time span of length $T$.  Suppose it visits state $i$ a total of $N_i$ times during that time.  If we measure the spacings between those visits, they will necessarily add up to about $T$ (it would be exactly $T$ if it started and ended at state $i$).  So by definition the *average* spacing between visits to state $i$ is $T/N_i$, or very close to that.

On the other hand, it's very easy to see (by linearity of expectation) that on average, $N = \pi_i T$, since that is simply what the probability describes.  This means $h_{ii} \approx T/N_i \approx 1/\pi_i$.  As $T\to \infty$ both approximations become sharper so that in the limit we have equality.